# the_content() AND apply_filters('the_content'... ) not working in second loop on the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with a website that has been working for YEARS. Suddenly something has changed (no plugins were added).

Basically, I have a "post" page that displays 1 post at the top and then a couple of posts later down the page. The problem I have is that in these secondary posts, after establishing a new wp_query object, the "the_content()" and even trying to manually dump "$second_loop_post->post_content" into an apply_filters function returns nothing. The "the_content()" returns NULL. The kicker? the_title() and every other call works just fine for pulling out information. I can even pull out the unformatted info. But there seems to be something wrong with basic "apply_filters" which is also affecting "the_content()".

See below. Basically, when I load the page and try to do a custom query (even without displaying anything beforehand), it won't work. If I remove the custom $wp_query below however, it will spit out the information for that post page. The problem is I need the second and third queries I do to also display this content information .... and nothing. I'm going crazy. Help please.

```
global $wp_query;
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1
) );

if (have_posts()):
   while (have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_title();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I would try to add post_type and/or post_status to your WP_Query. I've noticed in the past the query doesn't always return results if you don't give it more than just posts_per_page

Comment: For secondary queries I always try to use [`get_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755) which gives you an array. Then, if you need to actually use "the loop" (which is almost never for me), you can call [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) on each post instance followed by [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) when you are done. Very clean and officially supported.

Comment: Why would you empty out `$wp_query`? Set up your queries with their own variables and then `wp_reset_query()` after each one.